# Powershell Script Backward Compatability PS 7.1 to PS 5.1

Tags: powershell

I  found this [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65007983/powershell-process-list-with-arguments/68257208#68257208)
here at stackoverflow by [PMental](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11301839/pmental)
.  [zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42) helped me to get it running in PS (7.1) I am pretty new (very new) too PS and was wondering if that script could be made to run in PS (5.1)? No matter how I issue the command in 5.1 it will not run nor give any error message. Thanks for any advice or input.

Comment: Hi Santiago Squarzon, sorry for the delayed response. For some dumb reason it has stopped working even in PS 7.1. The command I used for it in 7.1 was Get-ProcessPlus firefox in PS 5.1 my normal script command is .\Get-ChkRoute.ps1 I have tried in PS 5.1 Get-ProcessPlus Get-ProcessPlus svchost  .\Get-ProcessPlus.ps1 svchost and none of which display any info or error messages.

Comment: Sounds like you just need to dot source your function before using it. So, first you dot source (note the 2 dots): `. .\Get-ProcessPlus.ps1` this loads the function on memory and then you can just call the function like `Get-ProcessPlus firefox`.

Comment: Hi Santiago Squarzon, well being so new to PS, I'm not sure what the dot source thing has to do with it, but, that is exactly what the problem seems to have been. Thanks for your help and have a great day!

Comment: Glad to know it worked :) have a good day u2

Comment: I thought I would leave you some explanation of why and how it worked when you dot sourced your script to load the function, so, nothing better to rely on MS Docs: [Script scope and dot sourcing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts?view=powershell-7.1#script-scope-and-dot-sourcing). I would recommend to read the entire document but I linked to the particular paragraph where it is explained :)